# Is there a function search on Microsoft Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I know a lot of users have trouble learning Office 2007 mainly because they rearranged how to access certain functions. Some say it was to make it more logical, but after decades of doing things the "illogical" way, it seems illogical to apply a new set of logic on the user.

anyway, what I'm wondering is with the new 2010 version, is there some sort of function search? Kind of like Vista and Windows 7, in the Start button, you can just type in the program or file you want, and it'll just find it for you, is there something like this in the 2010 version which allows you to search for certain features inside Word. (Eg. if I wanted to do a Word Count, I could just type in Word Count in the search instead of having to remember which ribbon it belongs to).

PS - this feature may already be in 2007, i just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: This would be a fantastic tool, and I have looked for one before. I have yet to find anything however, and it would take more time than I have currently to try to develop it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Office Labs created an add-in called [Search Commands](http://www.officelabs.com/searchcommands) which does this.

When you type in the Search Commands box, it shows a list of commands that match that search value, as well as where to find them yourself for future reference.

[image: office labs search commands]

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool available from Microsoft to do this, however you (or your users) may find Microsoft's [Office 2010 Migration Guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2010/09/07/download-our-free-office-2010-migration-guides.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only content search.  There are no well-known or simple names for all the functions anyway.  You could always try the search in Help if you are truly lost.

The ribbon interface makes it a lot quicker to find anything now, as functions are represented visually as icons and they are organised into task-based tabs.